# XDM stuck on login prompt

Tags: arch-linux, x11, openbox, xinit

I've recently attempted experimentation with Arch Linux, and have managed to get an install with basic utilities, a network manager, etc going. I plan to use the Openbox window manager, with (at least, for now) the XDM display manager. Here's what I ran in the terminal:

```
pacman -S xorg-xdm xorg openbox 
systemctl enable xdm.service
reboot
```

I then reboot the system, and copied `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` to `~/.xinitrc`.

```
cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ~/.xinitrc
```

I added the line `exec openbox-session` to the end of `~/.xinitrc`. I also ran `chmod +x ~/.xinitrc`, just to be sure. Lastly, I added `openbox` to `~/.xsession`, and made it executable, as well.

I reboot the machine, and am taken to the `XDM` login prompt. I'm able to sign in successfully, however I'm simply returned directly to the login prompt. I'd like to go from login, directly to the Openbox "environment".

I admit that there is much here that I'm unfamiliar with. I've used Linux for some time, however I've done little "technical work" with windowing systems, window managers, X11, etc, so I've likely made some trivial mistake, somewhere.

---

**EDIT:**

My `~/.xsession-errors` file contains the error `/bin/sh line 1: /root/.xsession: Permission denied`. However, using `lx -l` indicates `.xsession` is executable?

---

Not sure why but, simply making `.xsession` executable with `cmod` *again* seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour suggests your session script is failing for some reason. See if your home directory now contains a `~/.xsession-errors` file; if it does, it contains the error messages from your session processes.

Also, use `df -h` to check that the filesystem(s) containing your home directory and `$TMPDIR` are not 100% full; starting a X11 session requires creating a few small files to both locations, and if that fails, the session will immediately end, similar to what you're experiencing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My `~/.xsession-errors` file contains the error `/bin/sh: line 1: /root/.xsession: Permission denied`, even though `ls -l` indicates `.xsession` is executable.

Comment: Ok, well, I re-run `chmod` and, oddly, everything is working fine!